# Issue building Emacs's docs with texi2dvi - '-recorder' and '\openout' not supported

Tags: info, build, texinfo

I'm trying to build the latest version of Emacs from source, but I seem to be running into an issue. The binary itself works fine, but when it comes to building the docs, the `make` process runs into this issue:

```
make -C doc/lispref pdf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/drbluefall/.cache/pikaur/build/emacs-lucid-git/src/emacs/doc/lispref'
  GEN      elisp.pdf
/usr/bin/texi2dvi: TeX neither supports -recorder nor outputs \openout lines in its log file
make[1]: *** [Makefile:161: elisp.pdf] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/drbluefall/.cache/pikaur/build/emacs-lucid-git/src/emacs/doc/lispref'
make: *** [Makefile:976: lispref-pdf] Error 2
```

I'm not entirely sure what's up here, since I have the needed dependencies, according to Emacs's `PKGBUILD`.

Comment: I recommend `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Answer (score 0):

A web search suggests your TeX installation may be incomplete.

Eg https://lists.gnu.org/r/bug-texinfo/2016-10/msg00031.html

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer. Please summarize here the relevant info at that link.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with sources emacs-28.0.50 with some minor TeX warnings like underfull \hbox.

The result: Output written on elisp.pdf (1332 pages, 4682046 bytes).
Transcript written on elisp.log.

Your Makefile seem to refer to texi2dvi, but texi2pf would be required.

which texi2pdf 
/usr/bin/texi2pdf

Could you please provide the Makefile in doc/lispref

-Dieter